# Why our skin turns orange in color when we eat more carrots?

Tags: food-chemistry

When we eat more carrots,our skin turns orange in color.Does any chemical reaction takes place when we eat more carrots?What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly carrots are sources of carotenoids (precursors to vitamin A or provitamins)

Its not really a chemical reaction per se, Vitamin A (Vitamin A is a nutritional term for retinol and related compounds with its biologic activities) is a fat soluble vitamin that is mainly stored in adipose tissue when in excess due to the hydrophobic  nature hydrocarbon carotenoids.

However some is metabolised through various mechanisms e.g through cellular retinoid binding proteins and others.

a typical carotenoid:

[image: v]

These compounds contain carotenoid pigments.

Most carotenoids are stored in adipose tissue. Lutein and zeaxanthin  are specifically accumulated in the pigment layer of the retina, and cause a yellowish appearance of eyes when over-consumed.

Similarly over acculumulation of pigments in layer of skin can produce a yellowish hue which may signify vitamin A toxicity (or hypervitaminosis A).

However in my practice I have seen very few cases of such toxicity.